# Razor View Flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Having a brain fart... given this model:

```
public class Result
{
     public decimal Cost {get;set;}
}
```

And this extreme simplified view:

```
@{
     decimal resultsTotal = 0;
 }

<div>@resultsTotal</div> //need the total from the loop below here

@foreach(var result in Model.Results)
{
     resultsTotal += result.Cost;

     <div>@result.Cost</div>
}
```

I need to display the `resultsTotal` variable *above* the foreach loop. I realize I can `@Model.Results.Sum(x => x.Cost)` in the view, the model or the controller, the point is I *want* to avoid enumerating `Results` more than once. Is there away to buffer the results and update the div after looping through perhaps or? Yea I could also use `jquery`, but that smells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `helper` and write the results to a buffer:

```
@{
     IEnumerable<Result> results = Model.Results;
     decimal resultsTotal = 0;
     var buffer = new List<HelperResult>();
}

@foreach(var result in Model)
{
     resultsTotal += result.Cost;
     buffer.Add(ResultRow(result))
}

<div>@resultsTotal</div>

@foreach (var result in buffer)
{
    @result
}

@helper ResultRow(Result result)
{
    <div>@result.Cost</div>
}
```

Comment: This works, although instead of using `HelperResult` I tried just Appending a quick `StringBuilder` then `Html.Raw` it. Enumerates Results only once.

Comment: Yeah that's really not the right thing to be doing for something so simple.  I'd highly suggest doing whatever you need to do in order to get the model into a state where it can be displayed in the view without having to do calculations in the view.  Is there a reason that the data must not be looped multiple times?  Good luck my friend :)

Comment: @Luke yea I know the (performance) requirement is not ideal, but it is what it is. I actually moved everything to my Command and storing the generated html table in a `StringBuilder` as part of my model for output in my view.

Comment: I don't think you're gaining any performance benefit from this.  You're still looping through every item and then looping through it again from the buffer List.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
    IEnumerable<Result> results = Model.Results;

    @foreach(var result in Model=)
    {  
         <div>@result.Cost</div>
    }

    var resultsTotal = Model.Results.Sum(x => x.Cost)
}

<div>@resultsTotal</div>
```

`@{}` is a code block that you can use to execute code.  I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, as putting logic in the view is just down right dirty.

You should make this calculation within your controller's action method and pass it to your view via the model.

Something along the lines of this...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // ... get your results from wherever you got them from before, eg your service ...
    IEnumerable<Result> results = myService.GetResults();

    decimal resultsTotal = 0;

    var responseModel = new YourViewModel
    {
        Results = results,
        ResultsTotal = results.Sum(x => x.Cost)
    };

    return View(responseModel);
}
```

And then you can display the information that has been calculated already within your controller on the view, with a minimal amount of logic:

```
@foreach(var result in Model.Results)
{  
    <div>@result.Cost</div>
}

<div>@Model.ResultsTotal</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear, the `resultsTotal` div needs to display above the foreeach loop.

Comment: I could, it would still loop twice, once in the Sum method and once in the view I'd prefer if possible to only do it once.

Comment: There isn't really another way to do it without doing something really really bad like outputting your for loop to a string (some how?) first and then outputting it to the page after the output of the `resultsTotal` value...

Comment: @mxmissile modify the code provided by Luke. Let the service method return a response DTO that includes 2 properties. One for List<> and another for the count() / sum (). if you are using stored procedure you can do that by returning row count with the results and read it from your repository.

Comment: @HoussamHamdan where the data is coming from is arbitrary, again `Sum()` loops through the results anyway, that is what I am trying to avoid

Answer (score 1):

Move the logic out of your view and into your view model. Unfortunately, you haven't made very clear what type of calculations you're desiring to make, but, in general, just add properties on your view model(s) that return the results of those calculations and you can chain them if need be. For example:

```
public class MyAwesomeViewModel
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }

    public decimal Total
    {
        get { return Results.Sum(x => x.TotalCost);
    }

    public decimal AverageCost
    {
        get { return Total / Results.Count(); }
    }
}

public class ResultViewModel
{
    public decimal TotalCost
    {
        get { return Cost + Tax + Shipping; }
    }
}
```

Much as your example, I've just made up some stuff here to illustrate the point. Break down your calculations into discreet units and then build them back up. This not only simplifies the calculations, but also gives you access to component calculations, should you need them. Then, you can keep your view relatively logic free.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I think my question came across wrong, I'm not concerned about the calculations and where they occur, I *am* concerned about looping through the Results multiple times. The LINQ Sum and Count methods loop through the results (behind the scenes).

Comment: LINQ is pretty quick, but regardless, there's no way to do what you want. If you need to display the total before the for loop, you have to iterate twice.